# How to deploy a maven project that contain ejb,war and ear in ibm bluemix

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, ibm-cloud

i create a maven project that include EAR,WAR and EJB  and i waont to deploy it to ibm bluemix . i tested pulling  project from  https://www.hub.jazz.com and that project doesn't contain any EJB project .

So any one have a way to how to deploy a maven project that contain EJB,EAR and WAR to ibm bluemix .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[Cloud Foundry CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-tips.html)**,deploying War & Ear are using the **same command** in Bluemix.

```
cf push <your-app-name> -p <path/to/your/ear/yourapp.ear>
```

Comment: can i create a project from jboss developer studio that have another archetype not similar to the project that i pull it before ("from "https://www.hub.jazz.com" ")from  and  push it to bluemix .. have you any tutorial or steps to do it ?

Comment: original question is about deployment, now you are asking about creating project, Are you clear about your requirement?

Comment: yeah,because my objectif is to deploy a project that containe (EJB,WAR,EAR ) in bluemix  so i don't find a method that explain how to do it. so actualy i have more and more questions about it.

Comment: One bite at a time.

Comment: Have any one solution for this subject " my objectif is to deploy a project that containe (EJB,WAR,EAR ) in bluemix" ?